# Copy value of local variable to a global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the value of a global variable based on the local variable which is defined inside a function.

I read here on Stack Overflow to use the window object, but still it's not working.

```html
<input type="text" id="getCity" placeholder="Enter"></input>
<button id="btn" type="Submit">Submit</button>
```

```js
var z = 0;
$('#btn').click(function() {
  window.z = 1
});
console.log(z)
```

Here is the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/t18ofd65/8/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Move `console.log` inside `click handler` and log `window.z` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/t18ofd65/9/)

Comment: @Rajesh That I understand. But i want the updated value of z which is 1 outside the function.

Comment: `var z` likely isn't putting the value on the `window` object in jsFiddle.  This seems like a misdiagnosis of a non-existent problem in the first place.  If you change `window.z` to simply `z` in your jsFiddle and observe the value in the debugger, you'll see that it does in fact change.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I want the updated value outside the function. From inside I can very well access it. But how to access it from out of the function.

Comment: You are trying to `console.log` it before it's really changed.

Comment: Please refer [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/t18ofd65/12/)

Comment: @David I changed window.z to z. Still getting 0 as the output.

Comment: @RohitGirdhar: What output?  Where are you observing the value?  The code as shown in the question never outputs anything after the value has changed.

Comment: @David You can check the output in the Developer Console. Open it by Ctrl + Shift + J

Comment: @RohitGirdhar: The console isn't going to magically update the previous output.  You have to output the value *again* after you change it if you want to see the updated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fundamentally misunderstanding what attaching a click event is doing. This code does not run sequentially line by line

```
var z = 0;                   // Line 1
$('#btn').click(function() { // Line 2
  window.z = 1               // Line 3
});
console.log(z)               // Line 5
```

Line 1 executes, followed by line 2. But line 3 does not execute until *the button is actually clicked*. Line 5 executes immediately after line 2.

If you added a `console.log(z)` or indeed a `console.log(window.z)` inside the event handler (ie, after line 3) you would see it actually updates the variable.